# Runtime Error with Red Black Tree Balance Function

Tags: c++, algorithm, enums, tree, runtime-error

I'm getting a runtime error when running my red black tree balancing function and I'm not sure why. I've tried debugging it without luck so far.
Here's the function:

```
void rbbalance(Tree* t, TreeNode* n){ //n is x
while (n != t->root && n->color == BLACK){
    if (n == n->parent->left){
        TreeNode* s = n->parent->right;
        if (s->color == RED){
            s->color = BLACK;
            n->parent->color = RED;
            rotate_left(t, n->parent);
            s = n->parent->right;
        }
        if (s->left->color == BLACK && s->right->color == BLACK){
            s->color = RED;
            n = n->parent;
        }
        else{
            if (n->right->color == BLACK){
                s->left->color = BLACK;
                s->color = RED;
                rotate_left(t, s);
                s = n->parent->right;
            }
            s->color = n->parent->color;
            n->parent->color = BLACK;
            rotate_left(t, n->parent);
            n = t->root;
        }
    }
    else{
        TreeNode* s = n->parent->left;
        if (s->color == RED){
            s->color == BLACK;
            n->parent->color = RED;
            rotate_right(t, n->parent);
            s = n->parent->left;
        }
        if (s->left->color == BLACK && s->right->color == BLACK){
            s->color = RED;
            n = n->parent;
        }
        else{
            if (s->left->color == BLACK){
                s->right->color = BLACK;
                s->color = RED;
                rotate_left(t, s);
                s = n->parent->left;
            }
            s->color = n->parent->color;
            n->parent->color = BLACK;
            s->left->color = BLACK;
            rotate_right(t, n->parent);
            n = t->root;
        }
    }
}
n->color = BLACK;
```

Here's the rest of the information given to me:
The structure definition is as follows:

```
enum color { RED, BLACK };

struct TreeNode

{

    int key;

    enum color color;

    TreeNode *left;

    TreeNode *right;

    TreeNode *parent;

};

struct Tree

{

    TreeNode *root;

};
```

There are several helper functions that you can use to implement the program.

```
TreeNode* sibling(TreeNode* n) //return the sicilian node

void rotate_right(Tree* t,  TreeNode *n) //right rotate

void rotate_left(Tree* t,  TreeNode *n) // left rotate

color node_color(TreeNode* n) //returns the color of the node
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might be hitting a null pointer.  You should be checking for that if your not.

Comment: And you think you should not tell us what error you get?

Comment: It just outputs "***Runtime error***"

Comment: can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: I can't provide the stack trace unfortunately, the function is being tested with Moodle and it doesn't provide me that.

Comment: So "it" is "Moodle" that exactly is what?